# Java Program not running in cmd

Tags: java

I am able to compile the java program but not able to run it.
The problem is that java cannot open the `.cfg` file which is part of JRE 8.

[image: problem of running the program]

Comment: Do you have permissions to read `jvm.cfg`?

Comment: Advice for the future: **HOW TO COPY A TEXT FROM COMMAND LINE WINDOW**: 1) Press Ctrl+A to select all text. 2) Press Enter to copy it to clipboard. 3) Paste it here, surround it with 3 backtick marks `

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check if you have permission for running jar.
Then check it your runtime is same as JDK.

Check if you are typing command correctly:
`java -jar file.jar`
**Edit:**
It seems like your .cfg file doesn’t exist or it’s corrupted.
Check it and try rebuild it. If it didn’t work you have syntax error somewhere int cfg file.